# PHP's sleep function and client connections

Tags: php, connection

How does PHP handle client connection while doing sleeps?

Or put another way ... what happens if the client closes the connection to the server while a page is being processed?

Does it just kill the process, or does it continue to process the page until the end?

Since I'm not sure of the answers to the above how would I implement the following pseudocode in PHP.

```
Record user entered

while (user is still connected) {
    fetch changes in state since last awake
    send changes to user

    sleep(5);
}

Record user exit
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who knew?

Connection Handling Documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

From that page `register_shutdown_function` solves the problem.

Wonderful.